# connect live server from local server in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

How can I connect live server from local server in php mysql. I used below this code, but when I run mysql it throws error `"access denied"` error,then I replaced IP Address in placed of host name ,but again same error occurred .But all hostname/IP address,username,password,database all are correct. suppose host name=www.example.com, username=example1, password=12345, database=example2

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("example.com","example1","12345");
    mysqli_select_db("example2",$con); ?>
```

Comment: has example.com been set up to allow remote access (by defult mysql wont allow remote access)

Comment: how can i do this?

Comment: whats the host set for user example1

Comment: ok i set up remote access in my live server, is there any set up in local server?